# No Clue how to sketch energy portaits, and question about jacobian in dynamical system

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

I am so confused in regard to sketching phase portrait for conservative systems.

For example, I have one question which says find a conserved quantity for $x''=a-e^{x}$ and sketch the phase portraits for $a \lt 0$ $a=0$ and $a \gt 0$.

I also want to ask if what I did is allowed so far;

the first part I think I did fine, it is just

$E=(1/2)x'^{2}-ax+e^{x}=$Constant

Then I tried to compute the Jacobean, yet I do not know if it is valid but I got 
$$J=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -e^x & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

I also tried to solve for the fixed points, I got that we only have fixed points for $a \gt 0$ and they are $(ln(a),0)$ in that case the jacobian would predict a centre but since it is a borderline case I cant be sure.

So how on earth am I supposed to even begin to sketch these portraits? I really don't have much clue. Really looking for help I am very stuck  here. Is there a different way in which countours can be sketched? I know I would have 3 different ones for each possible a. Should I pick values of constant and solve for points?

Here is what it should look like for the case that 'a' is negative, zero and positive respectively. but i want to understand WHY.
Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If we write it as a system of first order equations, we have $x' = y, y' = a -e^x$. We now draw the phase portraits and arrive at those three. Are you asking how we go about drawing the phase portraits from that system of first order ODEs?

Comment: Yes but how do you draw the phase portait?

Comment: @Moo Yes that is what I am asking, how they got those portraits from the ode

Comment: 1. Is it really hard to plot level sets of $\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2}-ax + e^x$ ? 2. Speaking about centres: yes, you really have centre equilibrium here. This is because you have conservative system. Purely imaginary eigenvalues lead either to complex focus or to centre equilibrium, but it can't be the former because that would contradict conservation law. So it's only latter.

Comment: @Evgeny yes because I do not have experience with it. Can you please tell me how you would do it?

Comment: Okay then. Usually it's covered in calculus or somewhat similar course. I'll try to explain the process. So you want to plot $\frac{y^2}{2} - ax + e^x = C$ for some fixed $C$ and $a$. You can solve this for $y$ and get $y = \pm \sqrt{C + ax - e^x}$. You have to determine where $C+ax-e^x$ is non-negative for the square root to be taken. And then you just plot $y = \pm \sqrt{C + ax - e^x}$ over this interval. It's not necessarily to do this exactly, schematically is good too. When you change $C$ and $a$ you change how this interval of existence looks like, thus you get different pictures.